# Page is fetching external data... from where?

Tags: javascript, html

Looking at this page:
https://www.bitinstant.com/order

for "Destination" it has a select box, clicking it, one of the options are "bitcoin to email", looking at the source I cannot find that text so I know its fetching that text from somewhere else.

But the closest I have come to where that external text is coming from is this code:

```
<select class="float-right" data-bind="foreach: label, attr: { id: name, name: name }">
<option data-bind="text: label, attr: { value: value }"></option>
</select>
```

I am not familiar with the "*data-bind*" part, I'm guessing that it has to do with some JS framework.

Can someone help me find where the text "bitcoin to email" is coming from please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a call being made to

```
https://www.bitinstant.com/api/meta/exchange/providers?details=true
```

I found it by using the Chrome developer console. From there go to "Network" tab and look at the list of calls. By guessing it would be of type JSON it was easy to find from the list.

The framework looks like knockout.js.

Comment: Thanks! That was the URL I was looking for!

Comment: Had to thank you again :) I followed your thought train and found it as well, but thats just half... the other half is that thanks to you I learned something new! :) Cheers!

Comment: Great to hear it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Use web debugger (I used chrome's WebInspector) and you'll see few XHR requests. One of it is
[providers list](https://www.bitinstant.com/api/meta/payment/providers?details=true) which runs from `bi-lib.min.js`. Since it's minified, it's hard to show you code, but it should be trivial.
`data-bind` is a custom attribute and probably used to describe snippet for dropdown fill with received json.

Comment: Thanks, will look into WebInspector. You answered just a minute after Bemmu or I would have picked your answer as it essentially the same. Thanks again!